# Why might it be necessary to force rebuild a program?

Tags: makefile, embedded, stm32

I am following the book "Beginning STM32" by Warren Gay (excellent so far, btw) which goes over how to get started with the Blue Pill.

A part that has confused me is, while we are putting our first program on our Blue Pill, the book advises to force rebuild the program before flashing it to the device. I use:

`make clobber`

`make`

`make flash`

My question is: Why is this necessary? Why not just flash the program since it is already made? My guess is that it is just to learn how to make an unmade program... but I also wonder if rebuilding before flashing to the device is best practice? The book does not say why?

Comment: Would you mind to show us the makefile, please? It heavily depends on that.

Comment: Using Linux as a development host does not make this an [embedded-linux] tag question.  That is for when the _target_ is running Linux.  That is not the case here.

Comment: I'd say it's because it's a book, plus it's for beginners. Because of that, it's more important that it "just works", not that "it's optimal". The author likely wanted to ensure that by repeating the steps in the book you'll most likely get a working prorgram, even after you do some own "testing" (tinkering with examples on your own). That's the same reason why quite a few tutorials that you find on the internet make you do additional steps just to ensure that it's going to work - things like "remove everything in X directory", "perform `make clean`" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to ask the author, but I would suggest it is "just in case" no more. Lack of trust that the make file specifies all possible dependencies perhaps. If the makefile were hand-built without automatically generated dependencies, that is entirely possible. Also it is easier to simply advise to rebuild than it is to explain all the situations where it might be necessary or otherwise, which will not be exhaustive.

From the author's point of view, it eliminates a number of possible build consistency errors that are beyond his control so it ensures you don't end up thinking the book is wrong, when it might be something you have done that the author has no control over.

Even with automatically generated dependencies, a project may have dependencies that the makefile or dependency generator does not catch, resource files used for code generation using custom tools for example.

For large projects developed over a long time, some seldom modified modules could well have been compiled with an older version of the tool chain, a clean build ensures everything is compiled and linked with the current tool.

`make` builds dependencies based on file timestamp; if you have build variants controlled by command-line macros, the `make` will not determine which dependencies are dependent on such a macro, so when building a different variant (switching from a "debug" to "release" build for example), it is good idea to rebuild all to ensure each module is consistent and compatible.

I would suggest that during a build/debug cycle you use incremental build for development speed as intended, and perform a rebuild for release or if changing some build configuration (such as enabling/disabling floating-point hardware for example or switching to a different processor variant.

If during debug you get results that seem to make no sense, such as breakpoints and code stepping not aligning with the source code, or a crash or behaviour that seems unrelated to some small change you may have made (perhaps that code has not even been executed), *sometimes* it may be down to a build inconsistency (for a variety of reasons usually with complex builds) and in such cases it is wise to at least *eliminate* build consistency as a cause by performing a rebuild all.

Certainly if you if you are releasing code to a third-party, such as a customer or for production of some product, you would probably want to perform a clean build just to ensure build consistency.  You don't want users reporting bugs you cannot reproduce because the build they have been given is not reproducible.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer and I appreciate the added detail!

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the complete software is a good practice beacuse here you will generate all dependencies and symbol files path along with  your local machine paths.
If you would need to debug any application with a debugger then probably you would need symbol file and paths where your source code is present and if you directly flash the application without rebuilding , then you might not be able to debug certain paths because you dont get to know at which path the application was compiled and you might miss the symbol related information.

Comment: All of that normally happens for an incremental build also, so this does not answer the question, which is (paraphrased): _Why/when is an incremental build not good enough?_

Comment: @Clifford thanks for your comment but with increemental build , I believe it means you do changes for certain files and do a run  .If you are doing an increemental build first time , then it might do a rebuild if certain dependencies are not met based on how the makefile is written. I just gave an  answer with the use case based on the experience I had and where I did not had the symbol information as the paths were different and had to do a rebuild.

Comment: I understand that, but that is not the situation described in the question and is only _one_ scenario where it might be necessary.  Moving a project including its object code to a new location is an unusual scenario.  Generally a project comprises just the source code.